# Generate print Page using java script - window.print() not working

Tags: javascript, printing

I write this code that generate a html page And print that!
But `mywindow.print();` just print html Page without any Styles!
Or write this code not working at all;
I put my code there:

```js
$(".btnPrint").click(
    
    function PrintElem() {
        //debugger
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT');
        mywindow.document.open();

        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title> Mytitle </title>');
        mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />');
        mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" type="text/css" />');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body dir="rtl">');

        mywindow.document.write('<div class= "container" > <main role="main" class="pb-3">  <div class="card border border-dark"> <div>');
        mywindow.document.write('<div class="card "> <div class="card-body">');
        mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById('invoice-info').innerHTML);
        mywindow.document.write('</div > </div >');       
        mywindow.document.write('</div > </div >  </div > </div >');     

        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        mywindow.document.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState === 'complete') {
                this.onreadystatechange = function () { };
                mywindow.focus();
                mywindow.print();
                mywindow.close();
            }
        }

        return true;
    });
```

Comment: Your page is opened with the URL `about:blank`. There is no CSS file at `about:blank/css/site.css`. Try with full URLs

Comment: can you tell me how  use full URLs?????

Comment: A full URL would be `https://www.yoursite.com/css/site.css`. Just put the full URLs to your CSS files in your `<link rel="stylesheet"` tags

Comment: but at first run not work ! I have to refresh and again it work.:(